# uninitialized constant API::V1::PopularSchoolsController - Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, api, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting error while creating API in rails app. The error is:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant 
API::V1::PopularSchoolsController):
```

My folder structure is:

[image]

My routes:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :popular_schools
    end
  end
```

Controller:

```
class API::V1::PopularSchool::PopularSchoolsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @popular_schools = PopularSchool.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @popular_schools }
    end
  end

end
```

inflections.rb:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
#   inflect.acronym 'RESTful'
    inflect.acronym 'API'
    inflect.acronym 'V1'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your controller outside `popular_school` folder. Say that, into `v1` folder.

Or change your routes by adding namespace `namespace :popular_school` in them like below:

```
namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      namespace :popular_school do
       resources :popular_schools
      end 
    end
  end
```